# wp8 c sharp community create tables in sqlite

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, sqlite

Anyone knows if it's possible to dynamically create tables for sqlite using c#. I'm using the c sharp community class for sqlite. I can't find any documents on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will create a table called Task. Schema of table task should be defined as a class in C#.

```
// The database path.   
public static string DB_PATH =Path.Combine(Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "sample.sqlite"));   
// The sqlite connection.   
private SQLiteConnection dbConn = new SQLiteConnection(DB_PATH);
dbConn.CreateTable<Task>();
```

Here is a complete tutorial on [SQLite For Windows Phone App.](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/59b9d6/sqlite-for-windows-phone-app/)